# copy & paste between excel and html editor

Tags: copy, double, quotes, paste

Here's what happens when I copy from Excel to Dreamweaver or any editor Sublime Text,notepad. ...
I think the problem comes from Excel but not from my php code
To show you I copy directly from Dreamweaver or (Sublime Text,notepad)  to Excel after I copy what I pasted into excel and I paste it in the html editor.
The result is double double quotes

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document sans nom</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Paste from Excel to html editor

```
      "<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=""utf-8"">
<title>Document sans nom</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
"
```

Where is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Double quote is an escape character in Excel. Since you have multiline text in excel box it will add double quote at the beginning and end and add another double quote before all existing double quotes to escape it. And when you copy it copies with the quotes. Its not a problem with your HTML editor. You will have to search and replace all double double quotes with single double quotes.

Comment: I can not replace the double double quotes because excel does not find it but w i copy this value to an editor the double double quote appear

Comment: yes, so you will have to copy it to editor and then replace.

Comment: This is not possible because I work with a  database (mysql and php)
Then I find a track if i  remove the line break there is no probleme <!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Title</title></head><body></body></html>

Comment: i have this test i have add a line break betwwen </body>
</ht‌​ml>        <!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Title</title></head><body></body>
</ht‌​ml> the double double quote appear